# Im trying to make a movable rectangle. When you run this code it displays the pygame window but nothing else. Any ideas?

Tags: python, pygame

This is my code for my game. I am trying to display a rectangle i can move with <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> or arrow keys. But when I run it the window is just black and that's it. No rectangle.

```
import pygame 

class window:
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

window.height = 800
window.width = 600

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((64, 54, 16, 16))

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 1
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)

    def draw(self, surface):
        # Im guessing this is where the problem is 
        screen.fill(255, 255, 255)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 128), self.rect)
#making thi window
def makeWindow():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window.height, window.width))
# pygame loop
def loop(): 
    running = True 
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False 
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    makeWindow()
    player = Player()
    loop()
```

Comment: There is a lot to say here, but the first step would be to actually do something with your code: you create a player but then do nothing with it. So the code you wrote (e.g. `handle_keys` or `draw`) isn't called/used at all.

Comment: First, try [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) your `loop()` function, I think that's a good way to understand what it is actually doing (SPOILER ALERT: not much ;) )

Comment: I guess that would be my second question @Adam Boinet is how do I call a function that is within a class?

Comment: You either do `MyClass.method()` or `obj.method()` (with `obj` being a `MyClass` object), depending on what you intend to do. Reading [this](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/) will help you being more familiar with this kind of stuff.

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

To move the player with <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>, you have to evaluate the state of the keys in `Player.handle_keys` and to change the position of `self.rect`:

```py
class Player(object):
    # [...]

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 1
        if key[pygame.K_a]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_d]:
            self.rect.move_ip(1, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_w]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -1)
        if key[pygame.K_s]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, 1)
```

The argument to [`pygame.Surface.fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) has to be a tuple with 3 or 4 arguments:

<s>`screen.fill(255, 255, 255)`</s>

```py
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
```

`screen` has to be a variable in global namespace. Use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt):

```py
def makeWindow():
    global screen
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window.height, window.width))
```

In the main main application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

```py
def loop(): 
    running = True 
    while running:

        # handle events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False 

        # update position of player
        player.handle_keys()
        
        # clear display
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
         
        # draw scene
        player.draw(screen)
        
        # update display
        pygame.display.flip()
```

---

See the complete example code:

[image]

```py
import pygame 

class window:
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

window.height = 800
window.width = 600

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((64, 54, 16, 16))

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 1
        if key[pygame.K_a]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_d]:
            self.rect.move_ip(1, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_w]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -1)
        if key[pygame.K_s]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, 1)

    def draw(self, surface):
        # Im guessing this is where the problem is 
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0, 0, 128), self.rect)

#making thi window
def makeWindow():
    global screen
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window.height, window.width))

# pygame loop
def loop(): 
    running = True 
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False 

        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        player.handle_keys()
        player.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    makeWindow()
    player = Player()
    loop()
```